# Is there a non-constant entire function which is bounded on the real axis?

Tags: complex-analysis

> Is  there  exist  a nonconstant entire function  which is bounded  on the real  axis ?

My attempt : I think  yes  take $f(z) = e^z$, now real axis  have  $y=0$ that $f(z) = e^{x}$

Is its true ?

Comment: Is $e^x$ bounded?

Comment: yes if  $x$  $\rightarrow -\infty$@ThomasShelby

Comment: @jasmine Also known as "No".

Comment: @jasmine do you understand what the statement "$f(z)$ is bounded on the real axis" means?

Comment: yes@Omnomnomnom that mean  $y$ axis  is  $0$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about the function $f(z)=\sin(z)$ ?

Comment: sinz is unbounded ,  im not getting How  sinz  is bounded on real axis  ? @ MAximilian

Comment: @jasmine Its absolute value is less than or equal to $1$. That's bounded.

Comment: @MattSamuel that mean $\sin z  = \sin (x+iy) =  \sin x $   here $ y=0$,   is its true ?

Comment: @jasmine : $\sin$  is bounded _on the real axis_ - which is just what you asked for. It is only *un*bounded _on the complex plane as a whole_.

Answer (score 7):

With

$z = x + iy, \tag 1$

on the real axis $\Bbb R$ we have

$e^z = e^x, \tag 2$

which is clearly not bounded since

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} e^x = \infty; \tag 3$

on the other hand, taking

$f(z) = e^{-z^2}, \tag 4$

on $\Bbb R$ we have

$f(z) = e^{-x^2} > 0, \; x \in \Bbb R, \tag 5$

attains its maximum value at $x = 0$, and also

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \pm \infty} e^{-x^2} = 0; \tag 6$

thus $f(z) = e^{-z^2}$ is manifestly bounded on the real axis, and it is clearly entire.

Comment: thanks u @Robert lewis sir

Comment: @jasmine:  you are most welcome, my friend!